# Referencing a react component from its class method

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have a dynamic todo list I would like to add a "highlight" feature to. Each list item renders with markup for the highlight that should show only for the list item clicked.

```
export class Todo extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {input: '', todos: this.getOldTodo()};
  this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
}

  //shortened

  selectItem(i) {
    this.setState({selected: i});
    if (this.state.selected == i) {
    // --- this is the code that needs to change the right list items child's class  
      ???.props.childen[2].className = "active";
    // ---
      console.log("true")
    }
    console.log(i);

  }

  render() {
            //markup also shortened 
            this.state.todos.map((todos, i) => {
              return (
                                                                   //What do I pass to the method here?
                <li key={todos.key} className="todo-li-item" onClick={this.selectItem.bind(this, i)}>
                  <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
                  <span onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, i)} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>

                  // --- This is the child that needs its class changed when it's parent is clicked 

                  <div id="todo-select" className={"hidden"}>
                    <span id="todo-select-top"></span>
                    <span id="todo-select-left"></span>
                  </div>  
                </li>
              );
            })
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is painfully simple and yet so un-obvious as to what I use to do this in react, but hey I'm still learning. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @trueter answer is the answer you are looking for. Also, while it is not possible to change the "display" of component except from `render()` function, and thus the code in `selectItem` would not work, your access to `this.state.selected` is a wrong thing to do. Because the `state` of a component is not immediately changed in React. So, `this.state.selected` might still be pointing to previous state value. Better way to do it is: `this.state.setState({newState}, ()=> {this.state.selected == i ? \\..});` Here the function passed is called after React is done setting the `state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been quite close. Here's my implementation.
Key takeaway: Don't mutate the state object.

```js
selectItem(idx) {
  this.setState(state => {
    const todos = [
      state.todos.slice(0, idx),
      { ...state.todos[idx], selected: ! state.todos[idx].selected },
      state.todos.slice(idx + 1, state.todos.length),
    ]
    return {
      ...state,
      todos,
    }
  })
}

deleteItem(idx) {
  this.setState(state => {
    const todos = [...state.todos]
    todos.splice(idx, 1)
    return {
      ...state,
      todos,
    }
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.todos.map((todo, idx) => (
          <li
            key={todo.key}
            className={'todo-li-item'}
            onClick={this.selectItem.bind(this, idx)}
          >
            <span className="todo-item">{todo.text}</span>
            <span
              onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, idx)}
              className="delete-todo"
            >
              &#10005;
            </span>
            <div id="todo-select" className={todo.selected && 'active'}>
              <span id="todo-select-top" />
              <span id="todo-select-left" />
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I see what you've done, your've taken the todo list of filtered out every one that is not the index, nice implementation. But is there a way I can reference elements from a component method? Or is it not done like that in react? Also, in what way was I mutating the state? I was comparing, not setting it a value.

Comment: With reactive programming you will want to have your element update because of a change of data, not reference or modify elements imperatively. In rare situations you might require access to dom nodes directly [using ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). My comment regarding state mutation was merely an explanation of the cumbersome syntax I had to use to avoid mutation. Hope this answers your question?

Comment: Very informative thanks, I'll need to work on not doing things imperatively. Your code does change the class, but it does for every item, and not the one clicked. I came up for logic for this, but it deeded an `if` inside `className` and JSX hates that, let me know if you find a work around

Comment: { todo.selected && 'active' } should only attach the active class name to every item... when all items are selected. It's basically a short inline if statement. I recommend downloading the react dev tools to inspect the state of your todos array at runtime.

Comment: I'll have to close this as I'm going away, but you've helped me enough for me to find my way I think @tueter, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

- The list item can be a stateless component, so the `onSelect` and `onDelete` become callback functions.
- Deleting item with index may get you in trouble, since React will not re-render the entire list every time.
- I don't know what's inside `getOldTodo`, but `custructor` cannot wait. So it will be null initially, if it's an async function.

There is an implementation using ES6 syntax.
Each list item is stateless:

```
const ListItem = props => {
  const { todo, deleteItem, selectItem } = props;
  return (
    <li key={todo.key} className="todo-li-item" onClick={selectItem}>
      <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
      <span onClick={deleteItem} className="delet-todo">
        &#10005;
      </span>
      clicked
      <div id="todo-select" className={'hidden'}>
        <span id="todo-select-top" />
        <span id="todo-select-left" />
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

All events are handled by a stateful component:

```
export class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    input: '',
    todos: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const todos = await this.getOldTodo();
    this.setState({ todos });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
          <ListItem
            todo={todo}
            key={todo.key}
            selectItem={() => {
              this.selectItem(todo);
            }}
            deleteItem={() => {
              this.deleteItem(todo);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  selectItem = todo => {
    const idx = this.state.todos.findIndex(i => i.key === todo.key);
    const todos = this.state.todos.slice();
    const todo = { ...this.state.todos[idx] };
    // change
    todos[idx] = todo;
    this.setState({
      todos
    });
  }

  deleteItem = todo => {
    const idx = this.state.todos.findIndex(i => i.key === todo.key);
    const todos = this.state.todos.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({
      todos
    });
  }

  getOldTodo = async () => {
    //...
  }
}
```

Does this make sense to you?